# Difference between SharePoint and SharePoint Foundation?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Having trouble figuring out what the differences between these are.

Answer (score 4):

"SharePoint" is a general term for the entire suite of SharePoint products but it is broken up into three versions: 'Foundation', 'Standard' and 'Enterprise'.  The versions and their differences are detailed [here](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx).